# How can I output all columns on a group by without putting them in the group by clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
Name    Priority    Country    SomeData
Paul           1    USA             456
Paul           2    England        7898
Paul           3    Austria          56
Fred           2    Belgium         156
Fred           4    France         8979
Carl           3    Canada          569
Jane           1    Peru             69
```

I want to do something like this:

```
select Name, min(Priority), Country, SomeData
from dual
group by Name
```

But I don't want to group by all the columns.

Result should look like this:

```
Name    Priority    Country    SomeData
Paul           1    USA             456
Fred           2    Belgium         156
Carl           3    Canada          569
Jane           1    Peru             69
```

I know it's something simple but I couldn't find anything.

How can I do it?

Comment: You just want to show the row with the highest priority for each name?

Comment: In this particular case, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inline view (or CTE) to add an extra column ranking the data in the order you want, and then an outer query that only gets the highest rank:

```
select name, priority, country, somedata
from (
  select t.*, dense_rank() over (partition by name order by priority) as rn
  from your_table t
)
where rn = 1;
```

Quick demo with your data in a CTE:

```
with t(Name, Priority, Country, SomeData) as (
  select 'Paul', 1, 'USA', 456 from dual
  union all select 'Paul', 2, 'England', 7898 from dual
  union all select 'Paul', 3, 'Austria', 56 from dual
  union all select 'Fred', 2, 'Belgium', 156 from dual
  union all select 'Fred', 4, 'France', 8979 from dual
  union all select 'Carl', 3, 'Canada', 569 from dual
  union all select 'Jane', 1, 'Peru', 69 from dual
)
select name, priority, country, somedata
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by priority) as rn
  from t
)
where rn = 1;

NAME   PRIORITY COUNTRY   SOMEDATA
---- ---------- ------- ----------
Carl          3 Canada         569
Fred          2 Belgium        156
Jane          1 Peru            69
Paul          1 USA            456
```

or if you want to stick with grouping you can use [`keep dense_rank first` syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm):

```
with your_table (name, priority, country, somedata) as (
  select 'Paul', 1, 'USA', 456 from dual
  union all select 'Paul', 2, 'England', 7898 from dual
  union all select 'Paul', 3, 'Austria', 56 from dual
  union all select 'Fred', 2, 'Belgium', 156 from dual
  union all select 'Fred', 4, 'France', 8979 from dual
  union all select 'Carl', 3, 'Canada', 569 from dual
  union all select 'Jane', 1, 'Peru', 69 from dual
)
select name,
  min(priority) as priority,
  min(country) keep (dense_rank first order by priority) as country,
  min(somedata) keep (dense_rank first order by priority) as somedata
from your_table
group by name;

NAME   PRIORITY COUNTRY   SOMEDATA
---- ---------- ------- ----------
Carl          3 Canada         569
Fred          2 Belgium        156
Jane          1 Peru            69
Paul          1 USA            456
```

Comment: I'd advise to only use the second variant, because of better performance and clearer intent.

Comment: and, by the way: the second select expression should read only min(priority).

Comment: I meant "min(priority) keep (dense_rank first order by priority)" equals "min(priority)"

Comment: Ah, right. Yes, of course... thank you, I'll fix that.